# How to bundle only a component to one file js file and refer in another project

Tags: angular, webpack, gulp, bundling-and-minification

I am in a situation where in need to bundle my component to one js file. the reason is i need to add this in to another running project.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'sample-comp',
      templateUrl: './sample-comp.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sample-comp.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!';
    }
```

for example, this is my component. after bundling I need a single file below is my HTML and CSS 
sample-comp.html

```
<h1>
  test
</h1>
```

sample-comp.css

```
   h1{
     font-size: 15px;
    }
```

after reading I thought of using gulp as task runner and I need output something like `sample-comp.js`

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample-comp',
  template: `<h1>test</h1>`,
  style: `h1{font-size: 15px;}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

please suggest any way to achieve this using any plugin

Answer (score 1):

after few search in web i found out that there is gulp plugin with which we can easily achieve this [`gulp-angular4-embedfromurl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular4-embedfromurl) please read through the document find useful

Answer (score 0):

Declare an [NgModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule), add your component to the exports array, and import your module to your other module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports: [ AppComponent ]
  providers: []
})
export class MyModule { }
```

`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports : [ MyModule ]
  providers: []
})
export class MyOtherModule { }
```

You can use your `AppComponent` anywhere in your `MyOtherModule`.

Comment: Thank you for finding time to answer. But with this am not able to achieve what i want.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood your needs